# Why does my code throw "NameError: name 'ModuleNotFoundError' is not defined" error?

Tags: python

I'm installing locally the following Flask app: [SolarPi](https://github.com/Tafkas/solarpi). Since I had to install the raven  package and there are pull requests and issues unanswered on the github repo,  I assumed the code to be broken and not maintained anymore. Despite of my lack of proficiency on Flask and Python I decided to give it a shot and try and get it running.

When I run

`$ (.env) python manage.py server`

The code throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    from solarpi.app import create_app
  File "/home/path/solarpi/solarpi/app.py", line 7, in <module>
    from solarpi import public, weather, charts, statistics, tables
  File "/home/path/solarpi/solarpi/public/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/path/solarpi/solarpi/public/views.py", line 11, in <module>
    from solarpi.public.helper import get_operating_days
  File "/home/path/solarpi/solarpi/public/helper.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pysolar.util import get_sunrise_sunset
  File "/home/path/solarpi/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysolar/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import \
  File "/home/path/solarpi/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysolar/radiation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import numeric as math
  File "/home/path/solarpi/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysolar/numeric.py", line 140, in <module>
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
NameError: name 'ModuleNotFoundError' is not defined
```

As it is possible to check on file numeric.py

```
from math import degrees, cos, sin, radians, tan, pi
from math import acos, atan, asin, atan2, exp, e

current_mod = 'math'


def globals_import_from(module, name, name_as):
    """
    Does "from <module> import <name> as <name_as>" (globally)
    """
    ...
    ...
    Bunch of defs
    ...
    ...

try:
    import numpy
    use_numpy()
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    pass
```

the `ModuleNotFoundError` is just an exception clause.

What is tricky here is the fact that the exception "NameError", that is raised when a local or global name is not found, catches an exception thrown by another built-in exception, in this case "ModuleNotFoundError". Since those exceptions are built-in, I assumed that the code is just written to python 3 and not python 2 as stated. Am I missing anything here that would not lead to refactoring the whole code?

Comment: Python 3.x and Python 2.7 are essentially two different languages. 3.x has `ModuleNotFoundError`. 2.7 does not. You are using 2.7.

Comment: Yep, I get that. From the instructions the coder asks us to use python2 but on his code he uses `ModuleNotFoundError` which is from python3. Am I suppose to rewrite the code to fallback to the previous version? If yes, do you know how would I do that?

Comment: If ModuleNotFoundError is the only problem, I guess you can create a new exception class with that name?

Comment: Can't you use `ImportError` instead? It is python2 compatible.

Comment: I've skimmed through the source code and I'm not seeing anything that won't run in Python 3

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword I tried your sugestion and it worked!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just to clarify the comments: as many said, `ModuleNotFoundError` is only available in Python 3.6 and later versions, but Python 2 must be used. However the `ImportError` exception is available in Python 2 and 3, it's just a bit less precise.

Replacing `ModuleNotFoundError` with `ImportError` should work.

Comment: This answer should be corrected; ModuleNotFoundError is available from Python3.6 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still on Python 3.5 and run into the problem

```
    NameError: name 'ModuleNotFoundError' is not defined
```

for example when running sphinx-build or pipdeptree or from your own code, then go to PyPi and download and install the module  "importlib-metada", latest version in the "2" series viz 2.1.0.

The versions 1 and 2 series of importlib-metadata include a "compat.py" file which provides the missing 'ModuleNotFoundError' functionality.

Do not use the newer/higher 3 series versions because these are for python version 3.6 or higher, and thus no longer includes the ModuleNotFoundError code in the "compat.py" file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't a missing module, it's a missing exception class. The following code:

```
try:
    import numpy
    use_numpy()
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    pass
```

Is supposed to try to import `numpy`, but if it fails, just to ignore that failure and continue (`pass` = do nothing).

However, the code is trying to catch the exception `ModuleNotFoundError` - which doesn't exist in python2.7.

Just run your code with python3 instead.

Comment: I tried this solution and it cries ```python3 manage.py server 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flask_script import Manager, Shell, Server
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_script' ``` .  Doesn't work on my end.

Comment: This is just so confusing! Here I can see the `ModuleNotFoundError` which makes sense since I ran python3. But still confusing!

Comment: It looks like you create a virtualenv for your flask script, which contains all the modules, and a python2 instance. When you run it with python3, it can't find any of the modules inside your virtualenv. Easiest option is probably to create a new python3 virtualenv, install everything in there, and retry.

Comment: This piece of advice might be useful in a near future. Thanks for sharing!7

Comment: I don't think it's python 2/3 matter, but python <3.6 matter.